# Find Pattern (Not exact string) in .XLSX with Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, xlsx

I can find exact strings but I can't seem to find the correct function or syntax to find a pattern, for example [0-9] in an .xlsx. I can find that exact string but not matches for that pattern, which is supposed to be just a digit between 0 and 9. The reason for this is because I am using the Find function and that matches exact strings. I know this is possible to find a pattern but just cant seem to figure it out. I have to call the open of Excel due to my initial Get-ChildItem script does not work with .xlsx files. Below is the code. Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated. I have put 3 asterisks where I think the issue is but I just can't see what the solution is.

```
$SearchText = '[0-9]'
$path = "C:\users\username\desktop"
$output   = "c:\users\username\desktop\results.txt"
$files    = Get-Childitem $path -Include *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb -Recurse 


Function Search-Excel {
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
ForEach($file in $files)
{


$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
ForEach ($Worksheet in @($Workbook.Sheets)) {
    ***$Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find($SearchText)*** 
    If ($Found) {
        $BeginAddress = $Found.Address(0,0,1,1)
        [pscustomobject]@{
            FilePath = $Workbook.Path
            FileName = $Workbook.Name
            WorkSheet = $Worksheet.Name
            Column = $Found.Column
            Row = $Found.Row
            Text = $Found.Text
            Address = $BeginAddress
    
        }
        Do {
            $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.FindNext($Found)
            $Address = $Found.Address(0,0,1,1)
            If ($Address -eq $BeginAddress) {
                BREAK
            }
            [pscustomobject]@{
                FilePath = $Workbook.Path
                FileName = $Workbook.Name
                WorkSheet = $Worksheet.Name
                Column = $Found.Column
                Row = $Found.Row
                Text = $Found.Text
                Address = $Address

            
            }                 
        } Until ($False)
$workbook.Close($false)      }
    Else {
        Write-Warning "[$($WorkSheet.Name)] Nothing Found!"

    }}
} 
[void][System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$excel)
[gc]::Collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
Remove-Variable excel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
Search-Excel | Out-File $output -Append
```

Comment: Is your problem just related to the function `Get-ChildItem`? 
Generally I would try to use regex for pattern matching.

Comment: I dont think it is because get-childitem works with finding patterns in my docx script. I think it is due to me passing my $searchtext to the Find function. But I dont know of a way to pass a pattern. Because my $searchtext is basically a pattern, or should be.

Comment: The above code works if I want to find an exact string of [0-9] in any of the filetypes that I have listed in my $files variable in the directory of my $path var. But I dont want an exact string match, I want a pattern match.

Comment: I've used this as my main function, but it doesnt work on a few filetypes due to encoding/compression so I have to do separate functions for those certain filetypes. I have completed the docx function and it works fine, but xlsx is giving me issues, and of course pdf isnt going to work, but I will worry about that at a later time

    Get-ChildItem -Path \\$machine\c$\$path -Recurse | Select-String '\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}' | Select-Object | Format-List Path, FileName | Out-File $match -Append

Comment: I figured it out. I had to use the cmdletbinding and param functions to do it properly.